# Find a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a matrix $A$ such that $(A - 3\mathcal{I}_2)^{-1}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$

I dont understand what the question is asking and how to solve it!

Any ideas?

Comment: the question is: (A - 3I subscript 2x2) to the power of -1

Answer (score 1):

Just solve for $A$ "straight forward"

$$(A - 3\mathcal{I}_2)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Longrightarrow (A - 3\mathcal{I}_2) = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$
$$\Longrightarrow A = \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}^{-1} + 3\mathcal{I}_2$$

Now you just have to calculate it